# Record Windows Store app with Simulator on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I need to record a video tutorial for my Windows Store app. I know that there is many software for screen recording but I want to **record app experience with different resolutions, using touch mode and different orientations**.

Since my PC does not have touch mode and does not support orientation changes I thought that using **Visual Studio 2012 Simulator** would be a good option but it seems that it only allows to take screenshots.

Is there any way to record videos of Windows Store apps using Visual Studio simulator?

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: Just use a standard screen recorder. Fraps, Camtasia Studio, etc. Look up guides generally associated with video games and they should match your needs pretty well.

Comment: I already tried several screen recorders that allows me to select an area to record. I selected the simulator screen but when I rotate it the area does not rotate as well. Also the video resolution is not the same as the simulator resolution.

Comment: In order to do rotations, you'll likely have to do some movie magic (stop the recording, rotate, restart with the new selected area, concat the two clips together). With regards to the video resolution, there are two things to consider. First, the Simulator automatically downsizes the screen resolution so it fits in the window. So if you're running at 1366x768 and so is the Simulator, it will downscale accordingly. If you want to record at this resolution, you'll likely need to run your desktop at a much higher res. Secondly, the recording software needs to record hi-def, so make sure it can.